# ZF1 and dijit tab container the Zend_Dojo_Form does not show

Tags: zend-framework, tabs, dojo

I have a Zend_Dojo_Form built an want to show it in a view in this view it will be shown inside a tab container
but the form is never shown althouht it appears in the code view, the dijit menu I have also disappears from the page.
This only happens when I print the form inside the tab container , can't see nothing strange in the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
    dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
<?php 
$this->form->setAttrib("Height", "450px")->setAttrib("WIDTH", "550px");
 ?>
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"
tabPosition="left-h" tabStrip="true" doLayout="false">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Grupo: <?php print $this->idacgroup ?>" selected="true">
        <span><?php print $this->form ?></span>
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Anexar utilizador">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
    </div>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Remover Utilizador">
        Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why put your form inside a span? And... what is in your form?

Comment: The span was only to test the form output if it were inside a different tag to prevent the div of the dojo form to attach to the previous div container. Eventually I solved this with a workaround.
My form has normal elements nothing special it was build with Zend_Dojo_Form

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the Zend_View functionality for building layouts and tabContainer this is the code I used.

```
<?php

$this->tabContainer()->captureStart('main-container',
                                    array('design' => 'headline'),
                                    array(
                                        "tabPosition" => 'left',
                                        'style'=>'height:400px;width:800px'
                                     ));

echo $this->contentPane(
 'form1',
 $this->form,
 array('region' => 'top','title'=>'Grupo:' . $this->idacgroup),
 array('style' => 'background-color: white;')
);

$join = $this->render("group/join.phtml");

echo  $this->contentPane(
     'usersadd',
     $join,
     array('region' => 'left', 'title'=>'Adicionar Utilizadores'),
     array('style' => 'width: 200px; background-color: white;')
    );

$this->nstore++;

$unjoin = $this->render("group/join.phtml");

echo $this->contentPane(
 'userdel',
 $unjoin,
 array('region' => 'center','title'=>'Remover Utilizadores'),
 array('style' => 'background-color: white;')
);



echo $this->tabContainer()->captureEnd('main-container');
```

This worked out nice and I did another thing, in the "join.phtml" code I was using a div for the data store, this was causing the same issue and breaking the HTML so I changed the div into a span for the data store.